# VB .net 2003 to VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compatibility

I have applications that have been created by a third party. These apps were done by using Visual Basic .NET 2003 with MS .NET Framework 1.1. Now I'm in the need to be able to modify these apps, but it seems that at the moment there is only one possible software to purchase and that is the Visual Studio 2010.

Is it even remotely possible to use this newer version with these old creations, or do I have to rewrite the entire code?

If it is possible, I reckon if I make modifications with VS2010, it is impossible to do anything with VB .NET 2003 afterwards?

Comment: Try this first, *then* ask a question about it.

Comment: OK, I have to clear this out. If sometime later on someone with the older (2003) version has to modify projects after I have modified them with 2010 version, I would like to know if it is possible before I can justify buying almost 1700€ software. If I make unrepairable damage by trying something I don't fully understand, the cost will be even bigger.

Comment: You can all use the free Express editions.

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade the projects to VS 2010 and .Net 2.0 or 4.0 and work on them there.

It will not be easy to go back again.

Comment: "It will not be easy to go back again." Does this mean that it still is possible, even if it would be difficult?
I mean, if the project is upgraded to VS 2010, can I downgrade it so that anyone with VB .NET 2003 can still work with it?

Comment: @Jukka: If you manually make sure that you don't use any .Net 2.0+ goodness (generics, etc), and edit the version numbers in the project and solution before opening in VS2003, it may work.  I **strongly** disrecommend it.  You should all use a newer version.